# Is it possible to determine the working directory of another process?

Tags: winapi

Given a HANDLE (or ProcessID) to process 'A' is it possible **on Win32** for an unrelated process 'B' to determine the current working directory of process 'A' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought this may be possible using the same technique you can use to get an [external processes command line](http://wj32.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/howto-get-the-command-line-of-processes/) and there does seem to be a `_RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS->CurrentDirectoryPath` which sounds promising.

(The example doesn't state that the APIs are largely undocumented and that they are [not future proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28VS.85%29.aspx), so YMMV)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but it's non-trivial. The only way of which I'm aware is to use [`CreateRemoteThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682437%28VS.85%29.aspx) to execute [`GetCurrentDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28VS.85%29.aspx) in the context of the target program.

Comment: This is the future proof way because the place where this information is stored may change in the future.

Comment: ... and risk being detected as malware by AV programs.