# How to get the full file path from a document(.txt, .docx) opened using Process.Start that was edited and saved by the user?

Tags: vb.net, process, savefiledialog

I execute the documents by this way:

```
 Dim proc As New Process
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = sender.Tag
 proc.Start()
```

**For Example**: the document opened was a notepad. I wrote on it the phrase "Hello World!" then I saved it on an specific computer location as a .txt document and also I closed the notepad program. I'd like to retrieve the path where the document was saved.

Comment: 99% sure that's impossible, as have no control over the Notepad application (or any other than your own one(s)).

Comment: I agree with you in a 98%, so I still looking for a possible solution. Thanks!

Comment: There's probably a native function to get the WorkingDirectory of a specified process. But I'm not positive about this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2967713/5981756 _might_ do it, but that would involve a fair bit of work.