# How do i get the working directory of a windows process in java?

Tags: java, windows, working-directory

I would like to get the path to the working directory of a specific process (for example for the PID of the process). I am Not Talking about the working or current Directory of the process where my Java Code is running. Its a simple task with Linux, but for Windows i cant find a proper solution. Furthermore, it would be nice, if its a Command or a Framework for Java, because i will need the path in my Code. I am not looking for the path to the executable, also Not for a solution with wmic or process explorer. 
Already thanks for the help.

I already tried commands like tlist and wmic, but those solutions cant be utilize in my code. I am looking for a solution that i can use without special installations on Windows.

Comment: Do you mean the current process or another one? And if the latter, why?

Comment: Not the current process, another one! A monitoring tool needs the path to restart the process.

Comment: There is no API for that in Java.

Comment: Well, maybe i can find a cmd of powershell command. Nevertheless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JNI and JNA provide means to call directly into native libraries from Java code, and it is feasible to use these to call out to Windows libraries.

There is a github project that appears to be close to the need: https://github.com/kohsuke/winp.  Perhaps you can add the needed code and send up a pull request, or fork the project.

Note that any solution here is going to be windows-specific, meaning the application using it will not run on another platform.  Given the nature of the question, that doesn't sound like it would ever be a concern.

Comment: Thank you, i tried the project to get the Environment Variables, but it seems that there is no way to get the CD Variable. Still thank you!

Comment: Ahh ouch - looks like there may not be a simple API call for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967650/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-working-directory-of-another-process