# How can I get the current working directory of a running instance of VS Code in a program running on NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

In NodeJS, I need to "access" a running VSCode instance and see if the current working directory is a specific folder, i.e. "/home/foobar/Desktop/myproject".

Is that possible in NodeJS?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, see [Find out current working directory of a running process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/94357/550426) (`pwdx <PID>` and other methods). On Windows systems, see [windows batch command to determine working directory of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20576834/11107541) (suggestions to install non-native programs that do the job) and [Is it possible to determine the working directory of another process?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2967650/11107541) (how to do it with the Windows API, which I don't know if is accessible directly via NodeJS). At least on UNIX systems, you could just use [`child_process`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) (see also [Execute a command line binary with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643470/11107541)).

Comment: Thank you. I accepted this answer, even though I subconsciously expected some code. But I forgot to ask that in the original question. Hence, could you provide some code? But your answer is accepted, thank you.